# How to extract only time as Duration

Tags: go

I'm looking for a way to extract time from time.Time as time.Duration.

For instance,
"2022-11-25 10:07:40.1242844 +0900 JST"(time.Time)
to
"10h7m40s"(time.Duration)

```golang
func main() {
   currentTime := time.Now()
   d, err := time.ParseDuration(currentTime.Format("15h04m05s"))
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }
   fmt.Print(d.String())
// 9h57m54s
}
```

This code works, but it once converts time to string and then converts to duration,
which I think it is roundabout, and I don't like it.
Is there a better way to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to truncate the current time to the start of day, then use `time.Since()` to return a `Duration`:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func main() {
  now := time.Now()
  today := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, now.Location())

  fmt.Println(time.Since(today))
}
```